# Least square means confidence interval with Tukey adjustment balloons unrealistically wide in mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model

I have data from an experiment with two fully crossed treatments. Response variables were measured in two separate years. I fit a linear mixed effects model to a log-transformed response variable, with the two main fixed effects, interaction fixed effect, and random effect of year (using `lmer()` from the R package `lme4`). Then, I used the function `emmeans::emmeans()` to get the estimated marginal means for one of the treatments, and `multcomp::cld()` to do the Tukey adjustment and see whether any of the treatments differ. My issue is that with the log transformation, the Tukey adjustment causes the 95% confidence interval around the treatment means to become incredibly wide, many orders of magnitude higher and lower than any observed data value. This seems unrealistic. I was wondering whether this is an issue with my R syntax or whether I've set up the tests incorrectly.

Here is a slightly fuzzed version of the dataset, with names of factor levels anonymized and some random noise added to the data (as it's private) for a reproducible example.

Load packages and data.

```r
library(lme4)
library(emmeans)
library(multcomp)

dat_reprex <- structure(list(Year = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
 2), Plot = c(1001, 1003, 1009, 1010, 1011, 1014, 1016, 1022, 1023, 
 1024, 1027, 1029, 1035, 1036, 1037, 1040, 1042, 1048, 1049, 1050, 
 1053, 1055, 1061, 1062, 1063, 2001, 2003, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2014, 
 2016, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2027, 2029, 2035, 2036, 2037, 2040, 2042, 
 2048, 2049, 2050, 2053, 2055, 2061, 2062, 2063, 3001, 3003, 3009, 
 3010, 3011, 3014, 3016, 3022, 3023, 3024, 3027, 3029, 3035, 3036, 
 3037, 3040, 3042, 3048, 3049, 3050, 3053, 3055, 3061, 3062, 3063, 
 1001, 1003, 1009, 1010, 1011, 1014, 1016, 1022, 1023, 1024, 1027, 
 1029, 1035, 1036, 1037, 1040, 1042, 1048, 1049, 1050, 1053, 1055, 
 1061, 1062, 1063, 2001, 2003, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2014, 2016, 2022, 
 2023, 2024, 2027, 2029, 2035, 2036, 2037, 2040, 2042, 2048, 2049, 
 2050, 2053, 2055, 2061, 2062, 2063, 3001, 3003, 3009, 3010, 3011,
 3014, 3016, 3022, 3023, 3024, 3027, 3029, 3035, 3036, 3037, 3040, 
 3042, 3048, 3049, 3050, 3053, 3055, 3061, 3062, 3063), Trt1 = 
 structure(c(3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 
 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L), 
 .Label = c("control", "level1", "level2", "level3"), class = 
 "factor"), Trt2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L,
  3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L,
 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L,
 4L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("control", "level1", "level2", "level3", 
 "level4"), class = "factor"), Y = c(2158.59905970595, 
 1251.4727731083, 1790.19817919615, 1597.19282719814, 1687.0106965681,
 1720.75607746878, 1564.15753862752, 1505.82507506224, 
 1607.45705437054, 1570.36888939712, 1305.95650235435, 
 1233.34290117997, 1440.36874372446, 1209.82514463767, 
 1801.6777811149, 1548.6815875682, 1808.21301292584, 1442.22647693023,
 1514.35463381467, 1658.26138464109, 1309.91739898201, 
 1710.5053649517, 1406.81202399823, 1233.84694614133, 
 1523.13259673538, 1340.63244495632, 1336.91901503359, 
 1868.83212405745, 966.156768650265, 772.39479816532, 
 838.530758532424, 1674.51520638795, 1997.39554060529, 
 1565.87718877466, 1422.75213461409, 813.229634449323, 
 1013.53380296962, 2158.55146827853, 2022.86437017822, 
 1439.1910289597,
 921.481485470946, 1171.54630364696, 2043.22666236862, 
 1597.97904932079, 1674.86250712198, 1471.74181876526, 
 1579.25893093279, 2310.6112810042, 1942.56675761732, 1738.1611751111,
 1965.92272530422, 2218.76071019398, 2069.38801363651, 
 1740.44642106525, 1479.38268171168, 1596.78675731629, 
 2087.53773652064, 2187.30823864764, 1892.06356745912, 
 1502.64027585401, 1570.65804767824, 1572.770955274, 2470.56820319357,
 2114.27120093182, 1692.52887244199, 1343.34761356524, 
 1563.32633474988, 2263.51826447082, 2088.28208660775, 
 1884.99379164318, 1682.63161008498, 1608.09824983156, 
 2005.59693333264, 1989.74208915916, 2063.48565368801, 
 4087.35614940249, 3221.39128174976, 3511.60850378984, 
 3312.70958631815, 2970.00203271205, 3924.25537269975, 
 4059.0383884004, 3489.88303736939, 3764.75925683024, 2892.7642548966,
 3749.5717873939, 3225.41521326006, 3698.37915484814, 
 2488.68187948746, 1638.01249594836, 3601.60167217308, 
 3946.39929365291, 3127.45486313203, 2540.92642036889, 
 2577.01180410805, 3895.47710383669, 3924.81526007975, 
 2863.00503003766, 2367.2490438887, 2122.59795071745, 
 4216.63325128058, 4752.55394742371, 3101.96796396627, 
 2976.86553176957, 2686.22237849168, 3387.60400274547, 
 3304.85510168601, 3486.77455705152, 3345.00280941006, 
 3391.75323528612, 3531.80514761301, 3528.52241670405, 
 3572.2370720877, 3258.38960287764, 3438.79078961425, 
 4325.86549340203, 2766.72375854368, 3140.26873373657, 
 2963.30088543439, 3589.23886653641, 3711.42299265126, 
 3411.76855792187, 2977.88964743111, 3528.89001371156, 
 3904.40755581469, 4272.61145419705, 3704.68025651859, 
 3440.39876615046, 3382.23008003269, 3694.68849971889, 
 3291.59326651953, 3387.51868191258, 3477.14997107478, 
 3425.66753942855, 3983.9954520286, 3563.393971622, 3753.18202786702,
 2892.42937739966, 3146.63511644724, 2866.05355993634, 
 3561.36950588379, 3560.02686268737, 3347.43624676822, 
 3722.73867296726, 3757.75260207119, 3750.18381722575, 
 3198.38828218515, 3024.21870303111, 3304.45898172044, 
 3141.58457659908)), row.names = c(NA, -150L), class = "data.frame")
```

Log-transform response, fit model, and get adjusted 95% CIs for treatment 1.

```r
dat_reprex$logY <- log10(dat_reprex$Y)
fit <- lmer(logY ~ Trt1 * Trt2 + (1|Year), data = dat_reprex)
emmeans_trt1 <- emmeans(fit, specs = 'Trt1', mode = 'kenward-roger', 
    transform = 'log10', type = 'response')
cld_trt1 <- cld(emmeans_trt1, adjust = 'tukey', Letters = letters)

# Back transform confidence interval
transform(cld_trt1, 
          lower.CL.backtransform = 10 ^ lower.CL,
          upper.CL.backtransform = 10 ^ upper.CL)
```

The final output shows very unrealistic bounds for the confidence intervals:

```r
     Trt1 response        SE       df  lower.CL upper.CL .group lower.CL.backtransform upper.CL.backtransform
2  level1 3.337662 0.1615288 1.103493 0.6030081 18.47402      a               4.008742           2.978669e+18
1 control 3.354987 0.1615297 1.103493 0.6115121 18.40673      a               4.088012           2.551095e+18
3  level2 3.363528 0.1611005 1.048960 0.4493374 25.17779      a               2.814086           1.505895e+25
4  level3 3.396371 0.1615217 1.103493 0.6320819 18.24974      a               4.286294           1.777235e+18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, there is a difference between `transform` and `tran`. If we use `tran` instead of `transform`, we get

```r
> ### Output 1 ###

> emmeans_trt1 <- emmeans(fit, specs = 'Trt1', mode = 'kenward-roger', tran = 'log10', type = 'response')
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions

> cld(emmeans_trt1, adjust = 'tukey', Letters = letters)
Note: adjust = "tukey" was changed to "sidak"
because "tukey" is only appropriate for one set of pairwise comparisons
 Trt1    response  SE   df lower.CL upper.CL .group
 level1      2177 810 1.02 5.64e-05 8.40e+10  a    
 control     2266 843 1.02 5.87e-05 8.74e+10  a    
 level2      2310 857 1.01 3.17e-05 1.68e+11  a    
 level3      2491 927 1.02 6.46e-05 9.61e+10  a    

Results are averaged over the levels of: Trt2 
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: sidak method for 4 estimates 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log10 scale 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
Tests are performed on the log10 scale 
significance level used: alpha = 0.05 
NOTE: Compact letter displays can be misleading
      because they show NON-findings rather than findings.
      Consider using 'pairs()', 'pwpp()', or 'pwpm()' instead.
```

These (correct) results are a lot different. Also, notice from the annotations that the intervals are already back-transformed.

What happened when you used `transform` is that, due to a timing issue, the initial results were viewed as *not* being on a log scale, then were converted to the log scale -- giving you results on the log-log scale.

It is really more straightforward and safer to incorporate the transformation in the model itself:

```r
> ### Output 2 ###

> fit2 <- lmer(log10(Y) ~ Trt1 * Trt2 + (1|Year), data = dat_reprex)
> emm2_trt1 <- emmeans(fit2, specs = 'Trt1', mode = 'kenward-roger', type = 'response')
NOTE: Results may be misleading due to involvement in interactions
> cld(emm2_trt1)
 Trt1    response  SE   df lower.CL upper.CL .group
 level1      2177 810 1.02     23.1   204783  1    
 control     2266 843 1.02     24.1   213127  1    
 level2      2310 857 1.01     22.2   240105  1    
 level3      2491 927 1.02     26.5   234347  1 
... etc. ...
```

Now, why are the CIs so wide? One reason is that with the K-R d.f. method, the d.f., as shown, are all near 1, which essentially means that the sampling distribution of the EMMs is Cauchy -- very fat tailed, so fat that the mean and variance don't even exist.

But another aspect of this is that the d.f. for comparisons is much larger:

```r
> ### Output 3 ###

> pairs(emm2_trt1)
 contrast         ratio     SE  df null t.ratio p.value
 control / level1 1.041 0.0559 129    1   0.744  0.8793
 control / level2 0.981 0.0456 129    1  -0.415  0.9758
 control / level3 0.909 0.0489 129    1  -1.767  0.2939
 level1 / level2  0.942 0.0438 129    1  -1.274  0.5812
 level1 / level3  0.874 0.0469 129    1  -2.511  0.0630
 level2 / level3  0.927 0.0431 129    1  -1.625  0.3682

Results are averaged over the levels of: Trt2 
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
Tests are performed on the log10 scale
```

We have 129 d.f. for each comparison. If you prefer to see pairwise differences rather than ratios, you have to re-grid the results to the response scale. This uses the original d.f. of the means rather than that of the comparisons, so we have to override the d.f.:

```r
> ### Output 4 ###

> pairs(regrid(emm2_trt1), df = 129, infer = TRUE)
 contrast         estimate  SE  df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 control - level1     88.7 124 129     -233      411   0.717  0.8903
 control - level2    -44.2 107 129     -324      235  -0.412  0.9764
 control - level3   -225.6 153 129     -623      172  -1.477  0.4543
 level1 - level2    -132.9 114 129     -431      165  -1.161  0.6524
 level1 - level3    -314.3 171 129     -760      131  -1.836  0.2614
 level2 - level3    -181.4 132 129     -524      161  -1.379  0.5149

Results are averaged over the levels of: Trt2 
Degrees-of-freedom method: user-specified 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates
```

These intervals are reasonable-looking.

One additional reason that compact letter displays are so misleading is that it doesn't show important information about the comparisons, such as that the d.f. are dramatically different.

##### Addendum

Later, I noticed that outputs 1 and 2 have the same estimates, but different intervals; and those in Output 1 are very much wider. That's because of the `adjust` argument, which was applied to *both* the pairwise comparisons and the confidence intervals. For the CIs, the Tukey method is not appropriate because those means themselves aren't pairwise comparisons, and the adjust method was changed to `"sidak"`, as noted before the output. You can confirm that if you simply list `emmeans_trt1`, you will get the same intervals as in Output 2, and that if you do `confint(emmeans_trt1, adjust = "sidak")`, you get the intervals in Output 1. The Sidak-adjusted intervals are a whole lot wider because we are reaching for lower and higher quantiles of the *t* distribution (0.0063 and 0.9937 in lieu of 0.025 and 0.975) with about 1 d.f., and as noted earlier, the tails of that distribution are extremely fat.